# Python-Streamlit Security

Tags: python, django, streamlit

I'm using Streamlit for a web app. I built a system authenticator with streamlit_authenticator. When users log in, they can view specific data. I made a connection between Streamlit and MySQL. In this database, there are usernames and passwords, as well as specific data for users.

Is this approach safe for deployment on the internet? Do you know other ways?

For example, I tried with Django, but its difficult to integrate this with Streamlit.